# Handling large resource dependencies with maven

Tags: resources, maven

I have a resource that is quite large (over 100 MB).  I would rather not check this into the SVN because then users who do not depend on this project still need to download 100 MB.  I am using maven for the build system/dependency management.  How can I handle these resources using maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ressource is a jar or something similar, you can add it to your repository :

```
mvn install:install-file
  -Dfile=<path-to-file>
  -DgroupId=<group-id>
  -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
  -Dversion=<version>
  -Dpackaging=<packaging>
  -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
       <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
       <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
       <version>       the version of the file
       <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

If not, you have to find an other way in database for example, or in a shared directory, you're right not to put it in SVN.

Comment: My resource is not a jar.  I could make it a jar dependency.  I tried using the remote-resources plugin, which gets the jar out of the svn.  However, now every time I deploy the project that depends on the resource, it builds a 100 MB jar.  What is the advantage of remote-resources over a normal dependency?

Comment: You have to use remote-resources plugin only if you want to incorporate remote resources into your own jar. Normal dependency is just a link to an existing jar. Don't use remote-resources if you don't need to alter the existing jar (to add a license file for example).

Comment: Making a simple maven project for each dependency (usually just files in `src/main/resources`) works excellently.